# Parallelization of an openMP nested do loop using ifort

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I have a nested do loop in an openmp fortran 77 code that I am unable to parallelize, when doing the command export OMP_NUM_THREADS=14, the more threads I add the worse the results, when its " 1 " the results are perfect, but when I add more threads it gets worse and increases for instance it went from a 0.81 to 79388911. here's the code

```
C$OMP  PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED), PRIVATE(kp,i1,kt,j,kf,k,k2)
      
      do kp=1,np
      do i1=1,nleg1
    do kt=1,nt
      do j=1,nleg
    do kf=1,nf
      do k=1,nleg

      ap=(cp(kp+1)-cp(kp))*dx1(i1)*0.5d0+(cp(kp+1)+cp(kp))*0.5d0
      atp=(ct(kt+1)-ct(kt))*dx2(j)*0.5d0+(ct(kt+1)+ct(kt))*0.5d0
      aphp=(cf(kf+1)-cf(kf))*dx3(k)*0.5d0+(cf(kf+1)+cf(kf))*0.5d0
    

C 'LES COMP DES P ( PX, PY, PZ ) et ( Ki + P )'
      apx=ap*dsin(atp)*dcos(aphp)
      apy=ap*dsin(atp)*dsin(aphp)
      apz=ap*dcos(atp)
    
C VECTEUR Ki+P
      akpx= akix + apx
      akpy= akiy + apy
      akpz= akiz + apz

c       print*,akpx,akpy,akpz
C VECTEUR K01=0.5*(ks-k1) et K01+P


      akp01x=ak01x-apx
      akp01y=ak01y-apy
      akp01z=ak01z-apz
         
C -------------------------------------------------
C--                       ELEMENT DE MATRICE
      t1=tcs(alpha,az,-apx,-apy,-apz,akex,akey,akez,1) *fa(alpha,0) 
      qj01=tcs(al0,az,akpx,akpy,akpz,aksx,aksy,aksz,1)
     $*q0s(al0,az01,akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,ak01x,ak01y,ak01z)

      qj0=q0s(al0,az,akpx,akpy,akpz,aksx,aksy,aksz)
     $*tcs(al0,az01,akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,ak01x,ak01y,ak01z,1)

c   print*,t1
    tj1=t1*(qj01-qj0)

    

C The Integration Over P

    qs01=qs01+aw1(i1)*aw2(j)*aw3(k)*ap*ap*(cf(kf+1)-cf(kf))
     $*(cp(kp+1)-cp(kp))*(ct(kt+1)-ct(kt))*dsin(atp)*tj1/8.d0

      enddo
      enddo
      enddo
    enddo
    enddo
    enddo
C$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

I'm new to PARALLEL calculations so I don't really know how to use OpenMP properly, I used the commands above mimicing codes I saw before on the internet

Comment: Do you know what a data race is and how to avoid it? I am not familiar with Fortran, but it appears that some of your shared variables should be made private to prevent data races.

Comment: All scalar variables that are assigned inside a parallel must be private. Also, some of them (e.g. `qs01` in your code) may need a reduction. And last, if there are dependencies between the iterations, you can simply not parallelize the loop.

Comment: Try declaring as private the following variables: ap, atp, aphp, apx, apy, apz, akpx, akpy, akpz, ap01x, akp01y, akp01z, t1, qj01, qj0, tj1

Comment: Also, add the following clause to the OpenMP directive: `REDUCTION(+:qs01)`

Comment: If there are no dependencies, it should be enough to get a proper result.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Your code is hard to read because of the inconsistent indentation. I suggest to increase the indentation level inside every loop. Also, please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Note the above code is at least Fortran 90

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion of an approach of using implicit none and default (none) and explicitly defining all shared / private / reduction variables, as suggested in comments, to try to eliminate a race condition.
There are 3 external functions, which would also have to be checked for a possible race condition and that arguments are intent (in).

```
   subroutine wrapper_omp ( np,nt,nf, nleg1,nleg, cp,ct,cf, dx1,dx2,dx3, aw1,aw2,aw3,          &
                            akix,akiy,akiz, ak01x,ak01y,ak01z, akex,akey,akez, aksx,aksy,aksz, &
                            alpha, al0, az,az01, qs01 )
!  shared variables
    implicit none
    integer*4 :: np,nt,nf, nleg1,nleg
    real*8    :: cp(*),ct(*),cf(*), dx1(*),dx2(*),dx3(*), aw1(*),aw2(*),aw3(*),        &
                 akix,akiy,akiz, ak01x,ak01y,ak01z, akex,akey,akez, aksx,aksy,aksz,    &
                 alpha, al0, az,az01, qs01

    real*8, external :: fa, tcs, q0s    !  Are these functions thread safe ?

!  local private variables
    integer*4 :: kp,i1,kt,j,kf,k
    real*8    :: ap,atp,aphp, apx,apy,apz, akpx,akpy,akpz, akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,       &
                 f1, tc1,tc2,tc3, q01,q02,                                             &
                 t1, qj01, qj0, tj1

!   declare all variables as private / shared / reduction
!   hopefully provides some suggestions for solution
     
!$OMP   PARALLEL DO        &
!$OMP&  DEFAULT (NONE)     &
!$OMP&  SHARED  (np,nt,nf, nleg1,nleg, cp,ct,cf, dx1,dx2,dx3, aw1,aw2,aw3,            &
!$OMP&           akix,akiy,akiz, ak01x,ak01y,ak01z, akex,akey,akez, aksx,aksy,aksz,   &
!$OMP&           alpha, al0, az,az01 )                                                &
!$OMP&  PRIVATE (kp,i1,kt,j,kf,k, ap,atp,aphp, apx,apy,apz, akpx,akpy,akpz, akp01x,akp01y,akp01z, &
!$OMP&           f1,tc1,tc2,tc3,q01,q02, t1, qj01, qj0, tj1 )                         &
!$OMP&  REDUCTION(+:qs01)
      
    do kp=1,np
     do i1=1,nleg1

      do kt=1,nt
       do j=1,nleg

        do kf=1,nf
         do k=1,nleg

          ap     = (cp(kp+1)-cp(kp)) *dx1(i1)*0.5d0 + (cp(kp+1)+cp(kp)) *0.5d0
          atp    = (ct(kt+1)-ct(kt)) *dx2(j) *0.5d0 + (ct(kt+1)+ct(kt)) *0.5d0
          aphp   = (cf(kf+1)-cf(kf)) *dx3(k) *0.5d0 + (cf(kf+1)+cf(kf)) *0.5d0
    

!C 'LES COMP DES P ( PX, PY, PZ ) et ( Ki + P )'
          apx    = ap * sin(atp) * cos(aphp)
          apy    = ap * sin(atp) * sin(aphp)
          apz    = ap * cos(atp)
    
!C VECTEUR Ki+P
          akpx   = akix  + apx
          akpy   = akiy  + apy
          akpz   = akiz  + apz

!c       print*,akpx,akpy,akpz
!C VECTEUR K01=0.5*(ks-k1) et K01+P


          akp01x = ak01x - apx
          akp01y = ak01y - apy
          akp01z = ak01z - apz
         
!C -------------------------------------------------
!C--                       ELEMENT DE MATRICE
          f1     = fa  (alpha,0)
          tc1    = tcs (alpha,az,-apx,  -apy,  -apz,  akex, akey, akez, 1)
          tc2    = tcs (al0,  az,akpx,  akpy,  akpz,  aksx, aksy, aksz, 1)
          tc3    = tcs (al0,az01,akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,ak01x,ak01y,ak01z,1)
          q01    = q0s (al0,az01,akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,ak01x,ak01y,ak01z)
          q02    = q0s (al0,az,  akpx,  akpy,  akpz,  aksx, aksy, aksz)

          t1    = tc1 * f1
          qj01  = tc2 * q01
          qj0   = tc3 * q02 
          
!          t1     = tcs(alpha,az,-apx,-apy,-apz,akex,akey,akez,1) * fa(alpha,0) 
!          qj01   = tcs(al0,  az,akpx,akpy,akpz,aksx,aksy,aksz,1)   &
!     &           * q0s(al0,az01,akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,ak01x,ak01y,ak01z)
!
!          qj0    = q0s(al0,az,  akpx,  akpy,  akpz,  aksx, aksy, aksz)  &
!     &           * tcs(al0,az01,akp01x,akp01y,akp01z,ak01x,ak01y,ak01z,1)

!c        print*,t1
          tj1    = t1 * (qj01-qj0)

 
!C The Integration Over P

          qs01   = qs01 + aw1(i1)*aw2(j)*aw3(k)*ap*ap  &
                 * (cf(kf+1)-cf(kf))  &
                 * (cp(kp+1)-cp(kp))  &
                 * (ct(kt+1)-ct(kt))  &
                 * sin(atp)*tj1/8.d0

        enddo
        enddo
      enddo
      enddo
    enddo
    enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

end
```

I compiled this with:

```
set basic=-v -c -fimplicit-none -fallow-argument-mismatch -O2 -march=native -ffast-math
set omp=-fopenmp -fstack-arrays

gfortran omp_code.f90   %basic%  %omp%   >> omp_code.tce  2>&1

type omp_code.tce
```

Hopefully this restructure might suggest a way forward.
(note: this restructure is derived from your code provided and may have mis-interpreted based on your code omitted. It has not been tested.)